# Magento: add background image for active link in top navigation

Tags: php, magento

I want to add a background image for the link from top navigation which is associated with the current page that the visitor is viewing right now.

Basically the idea is to have different background image for the navigation menu link for active page.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great tutorial on this which is very useful and that did the things what I wanted.

[**Here**](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/navigation/add_home_link_to_menu_bar) it is.

Answer (score 2):

Magento adds specific class names to the body class based on what page you are currently viewing. The login page, for example, will have a body tag with class 'customer-account-login'. You can simply target that class to do your styling in the usual way:

```
.customer-account-login .header .links li {
    background-image: url('../images/some_background.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: But this is targeting all the `<li>` not only the `login li` when I opened log in page. Hence all the menu's have active image